# How to set delete flag in tables that contain foreign keys to other tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a main table containing a primary key and there is another TWO table which contains a foreign key to this main table. So if we set delete flag to the row of main table it will set delete flag to the child table also.

How do I write this query?

this is my create statement

```
CREATE TABLE LOGIN_DETAILS( LOGIN_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
GROUP_ID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GROUP_DETAILS(GROUP_ID), 
USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
EMAIL VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL, 
CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL, 
UPDATED_DATE DATE );
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the rows in the other tables to be deleted when you delete the row in the main table?

Could you provide the `CREATE` statements you used for setting up your tables and the relationship?

Comment: @jeteon this is my create statement                                             
CREATE TABLE LOGIN_DETAILS(
LOGIN_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
GROUP_ID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES GROUP_DETAILS(GROUP_ID),
USER_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PASSWORD VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL,
CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
UPDATED_DATE DATE
); I don't want to delete data i want to set delete flag in all 3 tables

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to include code. (Highlight the block and hit the `{}` button and it should get nicely syntax highlighted too. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking but if you want to delete records from multiple tables that use foreign key.
Use Cascading delete to delete rows from multiple child tables